# Java & GWT: Web-приложение с desktop-версией

Tags: gwt, java, база-данных, ios, веб-программирование

**Постановка задачи:**

Разработать web-приложение для пользователей Windows, Linux, iPad, возможно MacOS, не для iPod и других мобильных платформ. С desktop-версией для Windows, Linux, MacOS, способной работать без активного соединения с интернет и выполнять весь основной функционал. Основной функционал заключается в произведении вычислений и генераций .txt, .doc, .pdf документов, на основе выбранных на форме пользователем параметров и данных из БД.

**Предлагаемое решение:**

- *Основной функционал* готовить в виде общих библиотек (для использования в обоих версиях) на Java и БД sqlite.
- *Версия-web:* на клиенте только GUI на Java GWT, основной функционал выполняется на Java веб-сервере.
- *Версия-desktop:* GUI на Java Swing, основной функционал выполняется на клиенте.
- *Логику приложения* реализовать вместе с (на стороне) GUI, которая обращается посредством веб-сервера (web-версия) или напрямую (desktop-версия) к интерфейсным функциям общей библиотеки для выполнения основного функционала.

**Имеются вопросы:**

1. Используем NetBeans 7, настольные приложения Swing и веб-службы SOAP/REST на Java, там разрабатываются довольно просто. Есть проблемы с установкой и настройкой GWT. Насколько адекватно поддерживается в netbeans GWT? Альтернативы IDE?
2. Идея с общей библиотекой для основного функционала выглядит обнадеживающе, это только наши иллюзии или это вполне реализуемо?
3. Дополнение к п.2.: можно ли одно и то же хранилище данных sqlite использовать и на сервере и на клиенте? Какие еще есть альтернативы?
4. Дополнение к п.2.: имеются ли готовые библиотеки на Java для работы с документами форматов .doc и .pdf?
5. GWT используем для обеспечения работоспособности версии-web на всех вышеперечисленных платформах, могут ли нас ожидать проблемы несовместимости?
6. Desktop приложения на Swing по разному выглядят на Windows и Linux. Похоже, как выяснилось, потому, что компоненты Swing надстроены над AWT. Эта проблема решаема, т.е., можно ли оформить интерфейс так, что бы выглядело всегда одинаково?
   **UPD**
7. GWT приложение транслируется в JS во время выполнения на сервере, или приложение сначала транслируется в JS код и только затем развертывается на сервере?
   **UPD 2**
8. Дополнение к п.2.: имеются ли готовые библиотеки на Java для генераций .dxf документов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Для Eclipse есть очень удобный плагин для работы с gwt
2. Общая библиотека это хорошо, но, вероятно, будет много различий, ведь как-никак инструментарий для разработки gwt web приложений и desktop приложений весьма отличается. Всё зависит от того, что Вы собираетесь пихать в эту библиотеку, и что у Вас вообще за проект.
3. Всё зависит от поставленных задач и проекта.
4. [работа с .pdf](http://moradan.sopovs.com/2009/11/java-pdf.html),[работа с .doc](http://poi.apache.org/index.html)
5. Вряд ли.
6. Можно. [ссылка](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)
7. JS код компилируется вместе с приложением, на сервере уже хранится в виде JS. Исключение - hosted mode - режим, сделанный для удобства разработки. Для браузера нужно поставить соответствующий плагин, чтобы видеть приложение в таком режиме. Плюсы - возможность отладки и публикация изменений на сервер "на лету".

Comment: п.7. т.е. Java-приложение на GWT можно запускать локально на компьютере обычного пользователя?

Comment: 1. Не знаю, я занимался с GWT только в Eclipse. Ну вроде его все и рекомендуют.
7. Нет конечно. Hosted mode сделан для удобной разработки. Фактически приложение так же размещается на веб-сервере, просто java классы не компилируются в JavaScript, а работает в браузере это благодаря плагину-интерпретатору Java-кода.
А веб-сервер развёртывать на клиентской машине - это нонсенс.

Comment: п.1. Для GWT все таки лучше использовать Eclipse?  
п.7. Значит интерфейс для десктоп все равно придется писать отдельно. Разработки версий веб и десктоп хотели вести в одном месте. Если бы не поддержка iOS, то можно было десктоп-версию развернуть в веб как апплет. Вариант с JS для веб нравится больше, хотя и придется одно и тоже делать по два раза.

Comment: У меня локально работает Tomcat с GWT/SmartGWT на локальном браузере.
Этим сервлетам доступна локальная файловая система (наряду с СУБД).
(Пока, правда, в режиме разработки, освоения функционала).

Answer (score 2):

Как альтернатива Net Beans'у - Intellij Idea (есть платна и бесплатная, бесплатную нужно настроить).

Если gwt, то тогда ext-gwt: http://www.gwt-ext.com/demo/
По поводу 6-го пункта в swing скины, хорошая статья по этому поводу на хабре
http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/java/128755/

Answer (score 1):

Я использую Eclipse в подобных экспериментах. Вроде работает.

По внешнему виду SmartGWT значительно лучше GWT , а механизм связи с сервером тот же. Советую обратить внимание на него.

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#main это примеры.

А почему бы не сделать вместо десктоп и веб версий только одну - Веб (с локальным сервером и базой) ?

**UPD**

Поподробнее...

Я делаю в основном, как описано в http://code.google.com/intl/ru/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/gettingstarted.html .

Делаю 2 части в Eclipse. Клиентская транслируется в JS, серверная .jar. Они общаются по GWT RPC (это все есть в tutorial). Все исполнимое получается в war/ (Eclipse). Его содержимое кладу в webapps/ в Tomcat, который слушает порт 8080 (если пересекается с Oracle, то передвигаю на 18080).

Браузер соединяется с Tomcat и запрашивает html приложения. В общем, локальный и удаленный варианты не отличаются (так сказать, локальный web, если сервер/база установлены на машине пользователя).

Comment: Вариант с локальным сервером для дескктоп-версии рассматривался. Отбросили, т.к. для клиента должна быть простота установки и использования приложения, веб-сервера все-таки не ориентированы на обычного пользователя и иногда требуют вмешательства более опытного.  
Хотя, думаю, если *GWT-приложение сначала переводится в JS-код и только потом развертывается в web*, веб-службу делать на Apache Tomcat и БД на sqlite, то должно получится

Comment: <blockquote>У меня локально работает Tomcat с GWT/SmartGWT на локальном браузере. Этим сервлетам доступна локальная файловая система (наряду с СУБД). (Пока, правда, в режиме разработки, освоения функционала).</blockquote>  
Не могли бы по подробнее.

Comment: @Ildar, можно написать инсталлер, который будет ставить томкат и поднимать ваше приложение в один клик.

Comment: Вариант интересный, будем изучать.